# Do projectiles released by melee weapons deal melee, ranged or magic damage?

Tags: terraria

After the 1.2 update, there's a random Solar Eclipse event that causes hordes of powerful enemies to spawn. These enemies occasionally drop Hero's Broken Sword, which can be crafted with Excalibur and Night's Edge to create True Excalibur and True Night's Edge, then these 2 blades can be crafted with another Hero's Broken Blade to create the Terra Blade, the most powerful blade in the game. All 3 of these blades release energy projectiles when swung. Are these projectiles considered melee, ranged or magic damage for purposes of equipment bonuses and buffs?

Comment: Frostbrand does this as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are considered magic damage by the game. The terraria wiki states that the Terra Blade "is a Sword/Magic Weapon that fires sword-shaped projectiles." Also, if you kill a player with the projectile, it gives a death message that does not contain the word "terra blade" (or similar), rather it gives the name of the projectile, though this is not necessarily related

Comment: Do death messages matter for determining damage type?

Comment: Not nessicarily. On the wiki it states that the Terra Blade "is a Sword/Magic Weapon that fires sword-shaped projectiles."

Comment: So the second sentence is just unrelated trivia?

Comment: Well, I sort of used it to justify my answer,but it would have been better to use the description in my comment.

Comment: Also, all the weapons can be used as a melee weapon, but their magic does more base damage.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this by using different headgears with the terra blade. I can confirm that melee damage boosts the terra blade projectiles, not mage damage.

Comment: Just confirming - with a full set of Solar armor (melee class armor), with no other accessories, the projectile damage is ~130 on average. With Nebula armor (mage class armor), the projectile does noticeably less - around 100.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Not sure if the accepted answer is just wrong, or if the game has updated. 6 years is quite a while. Either way, I'm grateful I can boost my terra blade damage with higher defence :)

Answer (score 1):

After it shows the base damage it should say magic, melee, or ranged. For instance X sword would say 74 melee damage. This would mean that all damage done by the sword, whether it's a projectile or the blade, it would do melee damage. Hope this helps!

Comment: This provides insight in how to determine the solution, but does not answer the actual question being raised. Perhaps this should have been a comment?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Frank It quite clearly says "all damage done by the sword, whether it's a projectile or the blade, it would do melee damage". It may not be a particularly well-sourced answer but it is definitely an answer.